# Writing to an exact cell in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Great thanks for your help! This is my code now: I just need to fire once, so 1 iteration, is this the solution? Column B leaves one open space and then adds '2'. Probably because it looks at the index:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path(PATH)

file_to_open = data_folder / "excelbestand.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(file_to_open)

data_x = 4
data_y = 2

  
df.loc[df.index.max()+1, ['A']] = data_x

df.loc[df.index.max()+1,['B']] = data_y

df.to_excel(file_to_open, index = False)
```

Comment: Please post the code you've already written.

Comment: I did now in the comment below, sorry!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and move your code to there. Also, read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and format your code in a code block.

Comment: Ok I did David!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you first need to read the dataframe in pandas so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pandas.read_excel("name_your_file.xlsx",sheet_name = 'name_your_sheet')
num_iterations = 10 # Number of times you want to perform action
while i <= num_iterations:
    data_x = df['A'].count()
    df.loc[df.index.max()+1] = [data_x]
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path("FILE PATH")

file_to_open = data_folder / "excelbestand.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(file_to_open,sheet_name = 'sheet')
num_iterations = 2 
data_x = 4
i=0

while i <= num_iterations:
    data_x = df['A'].count()
    i = i+1
    df.loc[df.index.max()+1] = [data_x]  > Nothing happens when I fire this query.

Comment: If you want to perform sql-like querys then your question should state that : look into pandasql https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/

Comment: it is not about the sql part, its about adding a certain value to an exact cell in excel

Comment: You need to first read the excel file, I suggest pandas function pd.read_excel. Then you can access every row you ant via the df.loc or df.iloc method . Just remember it is zero indexed

Comment: Check my new answer, it should solve your questions regarding the use of iloc.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see pd.iloc is very powerful : df.iloc[ row number, column number] :
columns : A,B,C,D column number = 0,1,2,3

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path(PATH)

file_to_open = data_folder / "excelbestand.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(file_to_open)

num_iterations = 1
data_x = 4
i=0
##### In this while you are appending the count of column "A" to the end of column "A"

while i <= num_iterations:   
    df.loc[df.index.max()+1, 0] = [data_x]
    i += 1
###########code for adding to las cell of column B 
i2 = 0    
while i2 <= num_iterations:
    df.loc[df.index.max()+1,1] = [data_x]
    i += 1

df.to_excel(file_to_open, index = False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I edited my post, one more problem to solve Andres!